# EditTextPreference not hide password on orientation change

Tags: android, passwords, edittextpreference

In my android application I show the dialog in preference screen.Dialog will appear when user clicks on particular view.
I used EditTextPreference.
The code for EditTextPreference is as shown below:

```
<PreferenceCategory
        android:key="deep"
        android:title="@string/security_setting_edittext_hint" >
        <EditTextPreference
            android:dialogTitle="@string/security_setting_button"
            android:icon="@drawable/lock"
            android:inputType="number|textPassword"
            android:key="set_password_preference"
            android:summary="@string/set_password_summary"
            android:title="@string/security_setting_button" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

So when user enterd password through keyboard it appeares as hidden in edittext as shown in figure

[image]

but at same time if orientation of device is changed the password is displayed not as hidden in edittext as shown in figure

[image]

Please provide me a solution to hide password when orientation of screen changes.

Comment: Try android:inputType="numberPassword|textPassword"

Comment: Tried the same but issue remains same

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the screen orientation is changed, the view gets recreated. One way to handle this is having 2 seperate xml files for the layout. Eg. activity_main.xml corresponds to portrait mode, then you can have another file activity_main-land.xml for landscape mode. In this new xml file, set the properties of EditText as password.

Hope this works.